# Travis-ci is failing with React Internationalization

Tags: reactjs, travis-ci

I've been learning React for a short time but I faced a blocker using the **IntlProvider** from react-intl. I'm using English and French and the translations are working well locally. But the problem is that my  tests are failing on travis-ci but pass locally.  Below is the error that I'm getting on travis-ci console:

`Error: [React Intl Error MISSING_DATA] Missing locale data for locale: "fr" in Intl.NumberFormat. Using default locale: "en" as fallback`

I tried to look for a solution online but couldn't find any; I'd appreciate your help. Thanks